# LightningChart createProgressiveTraceGenerator not a function

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

i need to add LightningChart into my web page but having issue with  createProgressiveTraceGenerator
it says createProgressiveTraceGenerator  is not a function i have added "lcjs.iife.js" as well

Answer (score 1):

[`createProgressiveTraceGenerator`](https://arction.github.io/xydata/globals.html#createprogressivetracegenerator) is function from `XYData` data generation library. It's not part of LightningChart JS. If you want to use [`ProgressiveTraceGenerator`](https://arction.github.io/xydata/classes/progressivetracegenerator.html) in a web page, you also need to include `xydata.iife.js` script to the page. This file is part of the [`@arction/xydata`](https://npmjs.com/package/@arction/xydata) package.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="xydata.iife.js"></script>
    <script src="lcjs.iife.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```